# How to avoid "We need to know who to send this to. Make sure you enter at least one name" C#

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook, office365

I am sending emails with attachments from windows application by invoking outlook. Till last week it was working fine but now I am facing below message and email is not sent.
"We need to know who to send this to. Make sure you enter at least one name."

When I googled it then most of articles were suggesting to rollback the Microsoft office update. I removed office completely and then installed again but having same issue. 
I am using below code for sending emails.

```
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.MailItem eMail = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            eMail.Subject = "Subject goes here";
            eMail.To = "toemail@domain.com";
            eMail.HTMLBody = "Body";
            String sDisplayName ="sample.pdf";
            int iPosition = (int)eMail.Body.Length + 1;
            int iAttachType = (int)Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;
            Outlook.Attachment oAttach = eMail.Attachments.Add("pdf path", iAttachType, iPosition, sDisplayName);
            eMail.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
            ((Outlook._MailItem)eMail).Send();
```

Office version is 16.0.6741.2048, and it is registered Microsoft office 365

Adding error message image link.

Comment: wrap this line around a `try catch` `((Outlook._MailItem)eMail).Send();` also if you are getting any errors please state them. also restart the mail server

Comment: try catch is implemented on whole block of code and message appears as
"We need to know who to send this to. Make sure you enter at least one name."

Comment: When you say a "message appears" - is it an exception object in your program, or is it a Win32 GUI message-box created by Outlook's COM instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just created a new project in local and tested your codes, it's working perfectly. Try with full NameSpace **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook**

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem eMail = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.Application.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        eMail.Subject = "Subject goes here";
        eMail.To = "toemail@domain.com";
        eMail.HTMLBody = "Body";
       // String sDisplayName = "Resume.pdf";
       // int iPosition = (int)eMail.Body.Length + 1;
       // int iAttachType = (int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;
       //' Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment oAttach = eMail.Attachments.Add(@"‪C:\Users\Rahi\Desktop\", iAttachType, iPosition, sDisplayName);
       // eMail.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
        eMail.Send();
```

[image: Outlook Result]

Are you missing recipient?

```
Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;   
Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add("toemail@domain.com");
oRecip.Resolve();
```

Check this [Reference](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/165548/C-Code-snippet-to-send-an-Email-with-attachment-fr), hope it solves your problem.

Comment: facing error message "There must be at least one name or contact group in the To, Cc, or Bcc box."

Comment: It was resolved by adding a dummy contact address and changing it with recipient every time. :)